# Docusign use replyEmailAddressOverride to send signed docs to a different recipient

Tags: docusignapi

My company is trying to avoid having many Docusign logins for the group (group X) using Docusign. We were wondering about using one login to do the create, but override the email settings to have it go to members of group X without them having to have Docusign credentials. I was wondering if that would be possible with the replyEmailAddressOverride.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by using the ["Send On Behalf Of"](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/sobo.html) feature where you specify an email address in the authentication header in order to "assign" each transaction to a specific person with the same and unique credentials.

```
{
  "Username": "",//Email of Group X credentials
  "Password": "", // Password of Group X credentials
  "IntegratorKey": "",// Integrator Key of Group X credentials
  "SendOnBehalfOf": "" // Email of the specific person to be assigned the DocuSign transaction
}
```

If I understand your question correctly, I am not sure that using the `replyEmailAddressOverride` feature will accommodate what you need.
From the [official documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#/definitions/EnvelopeEmailSettings), this email will be used when the user decided to "reply" to the email sent from DocuSign.
Example in C# below :

```
EmailSettings settings = new EmailSettings
{
    ReplyEmailAddressOverride = "otherUserThanTheSende@fakeemail.com",
    ReplyEmailNameOverride = "Other User"
};

envelope.EmailSettings = settings;
```

If you configure the above email settings, when the signer receives the DocuSign email inviting him to initiate the signing ceremony, if he/she decides to reply to this email, the original DocuSign sender email will not be used but instead the email you have configured will be used.
Example, my "Frederic "account was used to create a transaction so the sender appears as "Frederic" in the DocuSign email. However, when I decide to reply, it doesn't go back to "Frederic" but instead to the user I have configured in the envelope :

[image]

[image]
But if I understand correctly, you want to send a transaction from a specific sender and this email override setting doesn't affect the transaction sender but the transaction reply.

Comment: When you do SendOnBehalfOf, doesn't that email address need to be one that is assigned credentials already with Docusign?

Comment: Per [DS Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html) SOBO is not recommended now with legacy Header.

Comment: @AmitKBist Sure, but we don't know which type of authentication Kathy uses yes

Comment: @KathyLori: To use SOBO, the individuals must have been first added as users in the DocuSign admin section

Comment: And for SOBO also, you need to have a member in your account but she is asking if she does not have to add them as a member in the account

Comment: @AmitKBist In this case, I don't know if that's possible

Comment: Currently, we are using SOBO. But one of the Docusign folks advised us to use this replyEmailAddressOverride and I'm not sure under what circumstances it is to be used. I searched thru SO and found no references to it.

Comment: Ok, then my answer would not be useful as you already use SOBO.

Comment: Does anyone know how to use this replyEmailAddressOverride property? Not one question here on SO about it. My bosses' boss was in on some conference call with Docusign and they recommended it, but how to actually use it is what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: @KathyLori. I have edited my answer to explain what the replyEmailAddressOverride  would do when used. But I am not sure that this feature is the solution to your issue.

Comment: So what you're saying is that if I am the recipient and I get the invitation to sign and instead of signing, I hit reply on the email, then it will go to this alternate email address. So the only way that this override comes into play is if I hit reply to the email I receive and not hit the signing button to start the signing ceremony.

Comment: Correct, from what the documentation stated and from my own testing, it seems that this is the only situation that this feature comes into play.If you hit reply, then you will reply to this email to the email of your choice. Note that this is on a per-transaction configuration.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use `replyEmailAddressOverride` and `replyEmailNameOverride` as present in [DS Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#/definitions/EnvelopeEmailSettings) then when an email goes to the signer from DocuSign and if they want to revert to that email then it will go the email which is mentioned in `replyEmailAddressOverride` property